# How to combine two controllers in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and I've got two seperate controllers that work fine separately, but when I try to combine them in the same page, on of them gets broken. You can check them out here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RUKCNUsiLLHja5BCsOXi?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/UkGEaquNkXGfUgbuYBki?p=preview

I've tried to combine both controllers like this:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['audioPlayer'], [ngSocial]);
```

But that breaks it as well. Do you think it has anything to do with the Ionic framework I'm using?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here's the working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/0eQZ0O?p=preview

Comment: How are they breaking exactly?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the two modules injected into one main ng-App?

Comment: Also, @Mike, you aren't including any of the Ionic script includes so it's not an issue with Ionic, but it means you haven't set it up correctly. See here for how it should work: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-angular-cordova-seed/blob/master/www/index.html

Comment: Yup had nothing to do with the Ionic framework I'll remove the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you show the third example where it actually breaks.  It looks like you should have:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['audioPlayer', 'ngSocial']);
```

If you're actually talking about combining modules.  The first parameter to angular.module is the string name of the module you're defining, the second parameter is the array of dependencies.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, just want to point out ops app module is called "main"

Comment: No problem, this is a bit of a point of confusion in Angular.  When you use angular.module('moduleName'); with only the string argument it looks up the module so you can add things to it, this assumes it was previously created by using the two parameter angular.module('moduleName',[]); where the second param is an array of strings of modules your module depends on.  Hopefully that makes sense and doesn't add to the confusion.